# Frequency of repetitive position in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am working to find out repetitive position of the following data frame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data ['league'] =['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B']
data ['Team'] = ['X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Z','Z','Z']
data ['week'] =[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
data ['position']= [1,1,2,2,2,1,2,3,4]
```

I will compare the data for position from previous row, it is it the same, I will assign one. If it is different previous row, I will assign as 1

My expected outcome will be as follow:

[image]

It means I will group by (League, Team and week) and work out the frequency.
Can anyone advise how to do that in Pandas

Thanks,

Zep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `diff`, and compare against `0`:

```
v = df.position.diff()
v[0] = 0
df['frequency'] = v.ne(0).astype(int)

print(df)
  league Team  week  position  frequency
0      A    X     1         1          0
1      A    X     2         1          0
2      A    X     3         2          1
3      A    Y     1         2          0
4      A    Y     2         2          0
5      A    Y     3         1          1
6      B    Z     1         2          1
7      B    Z     2         3          1
8      B    Z     3         4          1
```

---

For performance reasons, you should try to avoid a `fillna` call.

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df['frequency'] = df['position'].diff().abs().fillna(0,downcast='infer')
%%timeit
v = df.position.diff()
v[0] = 0
df['frequency'] = v.ne(0).astype(int)

83.7 ms ± 1.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
10.9 ms ± 217 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

To extend this answer to work in a `groupby`, use

```
v = df.groupby(['league', 'Team', 'week']).position.diff()
v[np.isnan(v)] = 0

df['frequency'] = v.ne(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: @ coldspeed, what if simple `data['Freq'] = data.position.diff().fillna("0")`

Comment: @pygo Simple but slower, hence avoided.

Comment: Thanks coldspeed. How about if position in week 1 has to be zero as it doesn’t hv any previous value if we group by. I mean I am tracking position changes from week one(this is just start of tracking)

Comment: @Zephyr week 1 is zero by default for all groups (as per my understanding of your problem).

Comment: @coldspeed, what is `v[0] = 0`  as assiging it zero

Comment: @pygo does the same thing as `fillna(0)`, but only needs to be done for the first item in the DataFrame uses you're grouping.

Comment: Yes. It is. Frequency at week 1 for all Team is zero

Comment: @Zephyr Then this should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Coldspeed. appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Coldspeed, When I applied it to my df. it showed me value error.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and [`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
data['frequency'] = data['position'].diff().abs().fillna(0,downcast='infer')

print(data)
  league Team  week  position  frequency
0      A    X     1         1          0
1      A    X     2         1          0
2      A    X     3         2          1
3      A    Y     1         2          0
4      A    Y     2         2          0
5      A    Y     3         1          1
6      B    Z     1         2          1
7      B    Z     2         3          1
8      B    Z     3         4          1
```

---

Using groupby gives all zeros, since you are comparing within groups not on whole dataframe.

```
data.groupby(['league', 'Team', 'week'])['position'].diff().fillna(0,downcast='infer')

0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
Name: position, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. If I want to groupby with League,team, week then work out the frequency, how would I add that. The sample data frame is already sorted but actual data is random.